# How to use MigLayout in Android

Tags: android, miglayout

I am new To android and I want to use MigLayout in Android.

1.how to use the miglayout tag in xml layout.

2.can i use my existing layout with Miglayout.

```
<miglayout>
     <relative layout>
    </relative layout>
</miglayout>
```

please help me.

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352781/how-to-use-miglayout

Comment: but the link explains about the swings.i need for android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen a port of mig layout for android.Download and add this library for using mig layout 
[click here](https://github.com/saynomoo/mig4android)

Also since the MigLayout class here is derived from ViewGroup you can use it with your existing layout.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help. i successfully fetched the layout.